# Need help fixing an old TIG welder, Relay is not working and I can't figure out why

Tags: relay, rectifier, debugging

I have an old TIG welder that uses a relay to HF (High Frequency) start.  I had a problem with it about a year ago and cleaning seemed to work, but now it's not even getting 12VDC to it.

Here's the PDF and the diagram is on page A (3rd page).  The relay in question is CR1 and it has wires 45 & 46 attached to the relay coil.  I applied 12VDC +/- to 45 & 46 and it closed the relay.  But it doesn't do this itself.  So it looks like the relay is working.

The relay CR1 gets its power from a rectifier.  It's an old selenium rectifier with several wires coming from it.  3rd page lower right CR1 and SR3.

https://www.millerwelds.com/files/owners-manuals/O315E_MIL.pdf

The HF works when the switch is on CONT, the switch has been checked (S6 bottom middle of 3rd page)

When I put a 12VDC test light on 45/46 it doesn't light up, but when I apply 12VDC +/- from a motorcycle battery, the relay coil works.

Q1. What should the output of 45 and 46 on the rectifier?  Should it be 12VDC + on one and - on the other?

Q2. is putting a 12VDC test light on 45 and 46 a valid test?

Q3. what should I test?

This machine has been working fine after I cleaned things up last year.  No idea what happened to make it stop working last year or now.  Last year I bought a brass brush and contact cleaner and cleaned things up, along with the relay contact, but I"m pretty sure the relay was moving last year, so IDK if it's a related problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like CR1 is intended to close whenever there is voltage on the electrodes, but it's not really involved when the switch is in the CONT position, nor is the bridge.

With the switch in the CONT position **and** switch S3 in the STD position, the HF is enabled by CR2, which in turn is simply powered by the 115VAC secondary. If CB2 is open or the 115VAC winding is faulty or S3 is not making contact, then the 115VAC won't be there.

If CR2 is worn out then the contacts may not close enabling the HF, the first thing to check (after S3 switch position and continuity).

The schematic is a slightly annoying mixture of normal schematic and ladder logic symbols and nomenclature.

[image]

Comment: I should explain what HF is used for in this case.  Older welders did a scratch start where you'd have to touch the tip to get the arc started.  HF start was introduced so that you don't have to make contact, you just have to be close and it would jump the gap in order to start the process without having to make physical contact.  Same concept as a spark plug jumping the spark gap.   The CONT position of the switch is for welding aluminum and acts as a cleaner, the HF is on the whole time.  The CONT is working, the start is not working.

Comment: Ah, maybe I misread it. CR1 is supposed to be on when there is voltage on the electrodes. So the voltage divider R3 should  have some AC or DC voltage across it (43 to 47, for example, as well as 43 to 48) under those conditions, and CR1 coil should have ~12VDC across it and pull in. Usually if Se rectifiers fail they make a rotten egg smell. If the Se rectifier has failed, then you could replace it with a silicon equivalent but the coil of CR1 would see a bit more voltage that expected due to the lower voltage drop of Si rectifiers, which could shorten the life of CR1.

Comment: So some adjustment would be required such as some diodes in series or perhaps R3 is adjustable.

Comment: R3 is adjustable and I took it off and cleaned the connection and verified that it is working as a rectifier, however, it's not putting out any voltage.  IDK what voltage it's supposed to have, but it connects to 43 and 48, so I'm going to check those next to see if they have any power, but because the machine actually does weld, I have to assume that at least 43 has power.  IDK if hooking a MM to 43 or 48 would blow it up or not.